# If statement which determines which React element to be rendered, weird behaviour

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I created a Sprite component which takes in 'icon' as a prop and determines which svg to render but I'm experiencing some weird behaviour.

I've had to resort to this method because I haven't been able to find a way to work with svg's (how to change their fill color!)

```
const Sprite: React.SFC<ISpriteProps> = (props: ISpriteProps) => {

const color = props.color || '#ACACAC'

let icon

if (props.icon === 'pin') {
    icon = <Pin color={color} />
} else if (
    props.icon === 'profile'
) {
    icon = <Profile color={color} />
}

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        {icon}
    </React.Fragment>
)

}

export default Sprite
```

Using the `<Sprite/>` in my `<Navigation/>` component like so

```
<Nav styles={this.state.styles}>
    <ProfileIcon onClick={this.onProfileSelected}>
    <Sprite icon='profile' 
    color={this.state.viewing === 'profile' ? '#5A4DB2' : ''} />
    </ProfileIcon>
    <LogoIcon onClick={this.onLogoSelected}>
      <h1>
        <img src={logo} alt="zestly" />
      </h1>
    </LogoIcon>
    <MessagesIcon>
      <img src={chat} onClick={this.onMessageSelected} 
      alt="messages" />
    </MessagesIcon>
  </Nav>
```

and in my `<CardBlock/>` component like so

```
const Card: React.SFC<{}> = (place) => {
  return (
    <CardOuter>
        <CardPhoto>
            <span>
                <Sprite icon='pin' color='#fff' />Fitzroy</span>
        </CardPhoto>
        <CardDetails>
            <div>
                <h3>Vegie bar</h3>
                <h4>7:00pm</h4>
            </div>
            <ProfileIcons />
        </CardDetails>
    </CardOuter>
  )
}
```

For some reason the icon prop I choose to pass in to the Navigation component Sprite is determining what is rendered for the Sprite's in CardBlock as well.

E.g if I make it 'profile' in Navigation it will make all sprites render the profile icon for Sprite as well even though I specifically pass in 'pin'. If I switch it to 'pin' in Navigation, all CardBlock sprites will render the pin icon.

I don't understand, is this some weird React render quirk?

EDIT: So I thought it was something to do with stateless functional component rendering so I changed Sprite to a Component

```
class Sprite extends React.Component<ISpriteProps, {}> {
public render() {

    const color = this.props.color || '#ACACAC'


    const icons = {
        'profile': Profile,
        'pin': Pin
    }
    const ActiveIcon = icons[this.props.icon]


    return (
        <ActiveIcon color={color} />
    )
}
}
```

Still no love, it's rendering ALL of them as profile icons if I pass 'profile' as icon prop to Sprite in Navigation component.

EDIT: Solved. It was something wrong with the svg's

Answer (score 0):

you could use classnames library to select what class should be added to React element, including svg. And in css you give fill rule that you want. https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

Comment: Sorry this doesn't fix my problem.